# What is theorem of arrest?

Tags: turing-machines

Someone mentioned it to me as something important related to the Turing machine but I can't find anything related to such theorem anywhere... Can someone help me or is the said theorem with the wrong name?

Comment: Sounds a bit like "theorem at rest" which might be a bad translation of the "halting theorem". That one is really important.

Comment: And... we have an upvote...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It was me. If you don't think this question would be of any use to non-native English speakers then go ahead and close-vote. I'm really not bothered.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: I see no use. Searching engines FTW.

Comment: It sounds more to me like (French) "arrêt" – possibly misspelled as "arrêts" (arrest) – which also points to the Halting problem ("problème de l'arrêt"). It's not a theorem though, but that could also be a translation issue. The only way to be absolutely sure is to ask "someone" what they meant.

Comment: The point is that I don't speak french. And I did search it to exaustion and found nothing remotely relating halting problem to arrest theorem... But if this question should not stay up on the grounds of not being generally useful I won't object.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: Why do you think that an upvote was warranted? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Because the OP demonstrated research effort, and because the question would be useful for anyone else searching for "theorem of arrest". Also because there were already two downvotes and I don't think that was a fair response to a genuine question.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: Why do you think that anybody else would search for "theorem of arrest"? And do you have any evidence that they would use it in the same context? Bearing in mind that the **only** result on the entire Google for this term is this very page? If anything, this question is harmful. The OP should _ask the person who said it_. They didn't. That's the very most basic research effort that they failed to execute.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I translate Japanese for a living. Pages like this are very useful.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: In such a situation, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/ would be a more appropriate fit. There is simply no authoritative answer to this question, only guesses.

Comment: Yes, but this question has nothing to do with Japanese. I don't know why you're making such a big deal of this. Stack Overflow isn't an exercise in groupthink. If you disagree with me, you don't have to vote the same way as me. Please find something more constructive to do. https://media.giphy.com/avatars/captainobvious/w5HJ3fnkcDMG.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In context, it sounds like a mistranslation of [*the halting problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

To be sure, you will have to ask the person who said it to you. They are the only ones who know what they intended to say, particularly as the *only* result on Google for `"theorem of arrest"` is this page.